# GIT - настройка автоматического деплоя

Tags: git, развертывание, bitbucket

Пытаюсь настроить автоматический деплой ветки с bitbucket. 
Указал url на сайте

```
http://site.ru/filename.php
```

при запросе на который будет выполняться команда

```
exec('cd /../project && git pull');
```

Обновления файлов не происходит, только владелец меняется с root на www-data, а вот если вызвать файл через консоль

```
php filename.php
```

то обновления успешно пройдут.
Если у кого-то уже был подобный опыт, прошу совета! У всех файлов сейчас полные права: rwxrwxrwx

Comment: Выполнять таким образом (Через exec) обновление идея не очень хорошая. Авторизация, сертификаты. разрешение конфликтов будет вашими проблемами. Воспользуйтесь пакетным сборщиком composer или библиотеками для работы с git  https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php , https://github.com/libgit2/php-git

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась, git требовал наличие ключей не только в root-директории, а также в var/www